# Add custom button in install4j

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to add a custom button (say, a retry one) on a configurable form, but have it placed on the bottom controls, next to the next and back buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 6.x, it is not possible to customize the navigation bar or an arbitrary screen with the buttons at the bottom of the installer window.

If you write your own custom screen with the API, you can override hasDefaultButtons() and provide navigation controls yourself. To move to the next and previous screen, you would call `context.getWizardContext().pressNextButton()` or `context.getWizardContext().pressNextButton()`. To cancel, call `context.getWizardContext()().pressCancelButton()`

Comment: Hey, but could you write your own screen ??

Comment: Would it be possible to set the hasDefaultButtons as false, and provide something similar to the default navigation buttons ?? as - https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/screens/Screen.html

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the hasDefaultButtons method.